The meaning of Lagrange multipliers with a constant objective function
In the method of Lagrange multipliers, it is well known that the meaning of a Lagrange multiplier $\lambda$ is the rate at which the extremal value changes with respect to the constraint. That is,
$$(\star) \quad \lambda(b) = \frac{\partial}{\partial b} f(x(b))$$
holds when evaluated at a solution of a Lagrange multipliers problem.
Now, suppose that the objective function $f$ of a Lagrange multipliers problem is constant (say zero), though with some constraints. This is useful, for example, when seeking a feasible set which satisfies several constraints simultaneously.
However, invoking $(\star)$ immediately yields that all of the problem's multipliers must vanish, regardless of what is being imposed by the constraints, which is clearly absurd.
How could this apparent contradiction be reconciled? Namely, how could any multiplier be nonzero if the objective function is constant?
My hunch is that the fault lies with the requirement that the multiplier must be a function of the constraint's value, $\lambda = \lambda(b)$. That is, perhaps the multipliers cannot be a function of the constraint's value once the objective function is constant?
Theorem 3.10 in Robinson's Introduction to Mathematical Optimization is brought as a reference:

